# doubt in list view

Tags: android

I have 2 lists, one on the left of the screen, the other list, on the right of the screen which gets dynamically populated based on the selected item on left list.

I move to the right list by pressing "Right" key from the left list.

Issue: Whenever I press right key from left list, the item that is currently selected is the item of the right list that is currently aligned with the left item. I dont want this to happen. I always want my 1st item of the right list to be selected. Can anyone help how to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, I don't know if it will work for ListItems. But with Buttons, there is an attirbute to set where the focus must go to! Eg: nextFocusRight

However, in these, the View Id must be specified, i.e the id of the view to which the focus must be passed. So am not very sure if it maybe useful with ListView items.

[link text](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#nextFocusRight)